# What will be the best way to update my NSString with appropriate NSArray value

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am trying to update my NSString value with the following code.

```
  NSString *string =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"array[0]%@",[array componentsJoinedByString:@"[0]"]];
```

This is the result I got.

```
array[0]1array[0]2array[0]3
```

However, I need this result, basically the number inside the brackets will be updated based on the number of objects in the NSMutablearray.

```
array[0]1array[1]2array[2]3
```

I tried using a for loop with [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%i]", i], but it seem to not have worked.

Comment: Have you tried with a **for** loop? That should be easy

Comment: What are you trying to do? Join all the vconponents and their indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested:

```
NSMutableString *finalString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *str, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [finalString appendFormat:@"[%lu]%@", (unsigned long)idx, str];
}];

// do stuff with finalString
```

Comment: Cool, never seen a method method before. Have to remember this